# ClassNotFoundException during Jsp compilation while deploying to appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp-tags

I recently upgraded from API 1.7 to 1.8.4 and now I'm having trouble deploying... It gets stuck because it can't find a class for a tag the jsp is using (neither tag nor page have changed in a long time).

The weird thing is the tag file seems to have been picked up fine and is found in the staging directory (although it is the only file there - even though there are many tags):

/private/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/1382335959467-0/org/apache/jsp/tag/web/util/panel_tagx.java

I'm not using maven or ant, just the Appengine Eclipse plugin, and then deploying with:

./appcfg.sh update /Users/mauricio/Dev/sts5/warprod

(warprod is just a copy of my entire project war directory - I do it this way so I can continue working on the project while I deploy)

Here's the error:

```
Oct 20, 2013 11:13:29 PM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
SEVERE: ERROR-the file '/WEB-INF/views/contentUnavailable.jspx' generated the following general exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.panel_tagx
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:224)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:52)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:685)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2522)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UninterpretedTag.accept(Node.java:1246)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:703)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:40)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.panel_tagx
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:224)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:52)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:685)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2522)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UninterpretedTag.accept(Node.java:1246)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:703)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:40)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:224)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:52)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:685)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2522)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UninterpretedTag.accept(Node.java:1246)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:703)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.panel_tagx
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    ... 20 more
Error while executing: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath /Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/impl/google_sql.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/impl/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/el-api.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/jsp-api.jar:/Users/mauricio/Dev/lib/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4/lib/shared/servlet-api.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/classes:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/1382335959467-0:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs-1.8.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-jsr107cache-1.8.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.3.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-enhancer-1.1.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/flexjson-2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/google_sql.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/janrain4j-1.1.0.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jericho-html-3.2.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-1.6.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.10.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/ocpsoft-pretty-time-1.0.7.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/persistence-api-1.0.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/restfb-1.6.9.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-js-resources-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-config-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-config-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-taglibs-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-taglibs-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE-sources.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-api-2.2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-core-2.2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-jsp-2.2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-servlet-2.2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-template-2.2.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/transaction-api-1.1.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-appengine-3.0.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-core-3.0.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-media-support-3.0.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/twitter4j-stream-3.0.4.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/urlrewrite-3.2.0.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/velocity-1.7.jar:/var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/velocity-tools-2.0.jar: -Dcom.google.apphosting.runtime.use_java6=false com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC -uriroot /var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp -p org.apache.jsp -l -v -webinc /var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/appcfg5050027279935979078.tmp/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml -d /var/folders/vf/5yfk4j290xd3l09yrkq9vf_m0000gn/T/1382335959467-0 -javaEncoding UTF-8 
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
Unable to update app: Failed to compile jsp files.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you remove the old jars from classpath and add new ones?

Comment: I tried it out while removing each jar in turn and it deploys if I remove just datanucleus-enhancer-1.1.4.jar, but then at runtime it complains that classes are not enhanced (I don't know if jar is needed for that or if enhancing is just broken).  I also tried deploying exact previous codebase that works with 1.7, using 1.7, and it worked fine with or without the dn enhancer jar.  Sorry for the slow reply.